# Cakephp MySql Query with WHERE

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have work function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->set('tables', $this->Table->find('all'));
    }
```

But how show only column WHERE owner = logged user?

Comment: How do you know if user is logged in? How do you authenticate user?

Comment: public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'tables',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'tables',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

Comment: public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}

Comment: Then @drmonkeyninja answer should be correct. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this where `$this->Session->read()` returns the current authenticated user:-

```
$this->Table->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array('Table.user_id' => $this->Session->read("Auth.User.id"))
    )
);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed the answer. Forgot to include `array` after the `conditions` index.

Comment: Undefined variable: tables
and
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You shouldnt use (deprecated) static access, better $this->Session->read().